# Converse character tables

Tags: representation-theory

This question concerns character tables. They seem to have so high number of algebraic properties that it seems to be impossible to construct a believable one that is not in fact a character table of any particular group. Question arises:

*Are there any character-table-like matricies that are not actual character tables?*

More precisely:

Let **extended character table** mean $n \times n$ matrix $M$ with associated $\mathbb{Z}^n$ vector $v$ (corresponding to class sizes) with following properties:

Let $S$ denote sum of entries of $v$.

- First entry of $v$ is equal to $1$.
- All entries of $v$ are positive
- $v_i$ divides $S$.
- All entries in the matrix $M$ are algebraic integers
- Rows of the matrix obey orthogonality relation as in usual character table (that is $M_{ij}v_j \overline{M_{kj}} = \delta_{ik}$)
- Columns of the matrix obey orthogonality relation as in usual character table (that is $M_{ij}M_{ik} = (v_j)^{-1} S \delta_{jk}$)
- Rows of the matrix are bounded by the first entry (that is $\forall_j |M_{ij}| \leq |M_{i1}|$)
- First column consists of positive integers (edit suggested by @Joppy)

Finally:

**Are there any extended character tables that do not arise from a group?**

Comment: @Thomas: needn’t all group character tables have entries in the subring generated by the *roots of unity*? That’s much smaller than the ring of algebraic integers. So I’d expect many character tables to not come from groups.

Comment: @Mindlack there are a couple of orthogonality relations we need to satisfy -- it seems that entries can't be too large, but maybe You are on the right track.

Comment: Should you add the condition that the entries in the first column are positive integers? Otherwise something like $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ i & -i \end{pmatrix}$ works I think

Comment: @Joppy Yeah, I guess your example works but that's not very satisfying. I'll add the additional criterion.

Comment: Also the algebraic integers are cyclotomic integers specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&-1&-1\\
1&1&1&-1&1&-1\\
1&1&1&-1&-1&1\\
2&2&-2&0&0&0\\
4&-2&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}?$$
Taken from the paper "Character table sudokus" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-023-01859-w
See also the reference therein.